# Установка monodevelop-database ubuntu

Tags: c#, база-данных, ubuntu, monodevelop, xubuntu

```
mono-complete
monodevelop
monodevelop-nunit
monodevelop-versioncontrol
```

Все вышеперечисленные пакеты установились без проблем, кроме `monodevelop-database`.

Пишет, что нет кандидата на установку. Как же скачать `monodevelop-database`?

Comment: Я верно понял, под пакетами вы имеете ввиду пакеты из репозитория ubuntu?

Comment: @tym32167 Именно так.

Comment: так на [сайте](http://www.monodevelop.com/download/linux/) этот способ записан как устаревший. Вы пробовали установить другим способом?

Comment: @tym32167 Так во флэт паке уже все есть?

Comment: Судя по инфе на сайте - да. Но я не пробовал, я на винде сижу